# In Resharper, how can I remove spacing between fields?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I have tried editing the line break to 0 but it just doesn't work, on code cleanup I want to make the following code below:

```
internal bool AllowTradingRequests { get; set; }

internal bool AllowUserFollowing { get; set; }

internal bool AllowFriendRequests { get; set; }

internal bool AllowMessengerInvites { get; set; }

internal bool AllowPetSpeech { get; set; }

internal bool AllowBotSpeech { get; set; }

internal bool AllowPublicRoomStatus { get; set; }

internal bool AllowConsoleMessages { get; set; }

internal bool AllowGifts { get; set; }

internal bool AllowMimic { get; set; }

internal bool ReceiveWhispers { get; set; }

internal bool IgnorePublicWhispers { get; set; }

internal bool PlayingFastFood { get; set; }
```

Turn into:

```
internal bool AllowTradingRequests { get; set; }
internal bool AllowUserFollowing { get; set; }
internal bool AllowFriendRequests { get; set; }
internal bool AllowMessengerInvites { get; set; }
internal bool AllowPetSpeech { get; set; }
internal bool AllowBotSpeech { get; set; }
internal bool AllowPublicRoomStatus { get; set; }
internal bool AllowConsoleMessages { get; set; }
internal bool AllowGifts { get; set; }
internal bool AllowMimic { get; set; }
internal bool ReceiveWhispers { get; set; }
internal bool IgnorePublicWhispers { get; set; }
internal bool PlayingFastFood { get; set; }
```

As I said I have already put the line break count at 0, what else do I have to do? Is this a bug or have I just not configured something correctly?

I have tried code cleanup but it just results in the space outcome, a space between each field.

Answer (score 0):

There are also the settings "C#\Formatting Style\Blank Lines" "Around field" and "Around single line field" that may be set.

edit: Just noticed, those are properties not fields. Look at the "Around auto/abstract property/event" and "Around single line auto/abstract property/event" settings in "C#\Formatting Style\Blank Lines".

Comment: Those are set to zero, yet code cleanup doesn't apply them. This is the problem in the question. I can confirm the same problem

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting under:

Code Editing -> C# -> Blank Lines -> Blank lines in declarations -> Keep max blank lines in declarations

This needs to be set to 0 to apply to any settings with a value of 0 under this section.